# IOS7 How to make sure the UIPickerview is selected and not the TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uipickerview

as suggested by Apple I'm using a UIPickerView in a UITableView. When I push/click in the large white Area between the Cell above and the PickerView Indicator (see picture) it fires an event for underlying TableViewCell and not the UIPickerView. Thus creating an assertion failure.
In Storyboards filled the whole Cell with the UIPickerView.

[image]

Does anyone know how to force the event to use the PickerView?

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting .userInteractionEnabled = NO for the cell that the picker is contained in? That will prevent any actions from happening when the cell is tapped.

Comment: Hey, this disables also the pickerview. Right now I'm using an if-statement, in Case the Cell ist touched and do nothing, but this cant be the best solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Yeah disabling touch altogether won't work as you've seen..  Maybe subclasss UITableViewCell and override become first responder..

```
-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder{
return !self.selected;
}
```

So that when the cell is already selected it allows the touch to pass through..

I've been fighting a little with embedded UITextViews inside tableview right now, similar thing.  The pan gesture recognizer in the table is always stealing the show in iOs7 where previous iOs versions handle it much better